# Performance of robot framework when evaluate keyword in runtime

Tags: python, testing, robotframework

I have plan to use Robot framework  on my test but have concern about the way it find keyword.
I want to test embedded device and need simulate input/capture output in high frequency, for example every 5ms. As I understand, Robot framework will find keyword in runtime and I concern how does it impact to test performance. 
And is there any way to improve it, some think like pre-compile keyword?

Comment: Before worrying about performance, have you actually tried anything to see if there's a performance problem?

Comment: I'm considering between pytest and robot framework and use as framework to create test case. I tried with simple test case and performance is not good as pytest but acceptable. But I'm not sure about complex test case will be create test case in future. On other hand, I still want to use keyword oriented approach of robot framework

Comment: It should just take you a few minutes to write a simple test case that calls a keyword 100 times. You can then examine the log to see how many times it can call the keyword in one second.